# How to leverage spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I want to convert an application which is currently using static INSTANCE variables to spring bean though config class but it has multiple dependency so I am not able to get it done.Classes looks like:

```
Class A{
private static final A INSTANCE = new A();

    // Prevent separate instantiation
    private A()
    {
    }

    public static A getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

class B is another class.

```
class B{

private static final B INSTANCE = new B();

    A a;

    private B()
    {
        A = A.getInstance();
    }

    public static B getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

class C extends class D and calls its super constructor.

```
class C extends D {
public C(final StringPool stringPool, final B<?> b, final B<?> bi, final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(stringPool);
        this.b = b;
        this.bi = bi;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public C(final StringPool stringPool, final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this(stringPool, B.getInstance(), D.getInstance(), objectMapper);
    }
}
```

Class D extends class M and calls its constructor.
Class D extends M{

```
    public D(final StringPool stringPool)
    {
        super(stringPool);
    }
}

Class M{
 private final StringPool stringPool;

    private final A a;

    public M(StringPool stringPool)
    {
        this.stringPool = stringPool;
        a = A.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change each class constructor to public with parameters for its dependencies.  Make each class a spring bean by marking it with  an `@Component` or `@Service`.  The Spring IoC container will create an instance (singular instance by default) of each class and use the public constructor to inject the required dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewS, but I  want to create object of class C, and if I removed method getInstance from class A and B, then in this case how to change constructor of C class, is it possible to do without new Operator?

Comment: Yes - as mentioned in my earlier comment, make classes `A` and `B` spring managed beans by marking them as an `@Component` or `@Service`.  And similarly, mark class `C` as an `@Component` or `@Service`, and add `A` and `B`  to `C`'s constructor.  The spring IoC container will create the instances and wire the dependencies on your behalf.

Comment: @AndrewS I am not aware how to add A and B to C's Constructor without creating new object.could you please write a code snippet?

Comment: Read about Spring's [IoC container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html) which avoids the need to use the `new` keyword for dependencies.  Then search for examples like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring).